# get unique elements count jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following HTML

```
<input type="hidden" name="product_id" value = "1" class="product_id" />
<input type="hidden" name="product_id" value = "2" class="product_id" />
<input type="hidden" name="product_id" value = "5" class="product_id" />
<input type="hidden" name="product_id" value = "1" class="product_id" />
<input type="hidden" name="product_id" value = "2" class="product_id" />
<input type="hidden" name="product_id" value = "2" class="product_id" />
```

How can i get the `count` of `Unique` elements (Unique Value of elements) ?

Is this possible `without looping` ?

Expected Result :

```
UNIQUE ID  COUNT
-----------------
  1          2  
  2          3
  5          1
```

> What i have tried is something like below, But the problem with this
>   approach is that it will loop all the elements.As you can see that on
>   first iteration we can understand the count of `product_id` of `1`, So it need to skip any other elements with same `product_id`. I
>   have bunch of elements and i will not prefer looping all the elements.

```
$(".product_id").each( function(){

  //CHECK THE COUNT AND SAVE IT TO SOME ARRAY

});
```

Update :

> Its Okay to downvote, But it will be very helpful if you put a comment
>   for that down vote. I specifically stated `without` looping because i
>   though that sometime it may possible with jQuery's powerfull CSS
>   selectors.

Comment: It's not possible without looping through the `<input>` elements at least once....

Comment: @ssilas777 none of them have the same ID...

Comment: I just noticed it and deleted my comment

Comment: @sweetamylase its OK to loop at least once, But if one got its count then do not repeat that again.

Comment: You would have to loop. What have you tried? How can you expect someone to just give you the answer without trying anything?

Comment: @Red your question wasn't clear about allowing to loop at least once

Comment: @Red please see updated answer.  There's no point e.g. finding the first value `n` and then doing `$('.product_id[value="n"]')` because that would be ~O(n^2) instead of O(n).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accumulate the values using an object as a key -> count pair, although it can't be done without looping over the elements, whether with an explicit loop or a helper function such as `.each`:

```
var count = {};
$('.product_id').each(function() {
    count[this.value] = count[this.value] + 1 || 1;
});
```

You'll then have to loop *again* to iterate over the counted values.

Whilst you *could* use a jQuery selector to count all elements that match the same value, it would actually be substantially less efficient than just iterating over every element.  The code presented here is O(n) but the alternative algorithm of finding each new unique value and then counting how many times it occurs would be approximately O(n^2)

Comment: The asker specifically said if it could be done *without looping*. Using `.each()` is *looping*....

Comment: I think he's just pulling your leg, the question was is it possible without looping, not how to do it o_O Although I'm sure the person who was asking the question really wants how to do it.

Comment: @Alnitak I know it cannot be done without looping. Red just clarified he is ok with looping at least once >.> So you're answer is good.

Comment: @spullen Pardon me, I never thought something like that. its just the matter of improving our skills.

Answer (score 0):

Grab the length of all of the input with the value you want to count.

`$("input[value='1']").length;`

this only works if we know the value

Comment: Here, The problem is that i cant guess the value.

Comment: ah, I thought we knew the values